# Angular @Input adding a function possible?

Tags: angular, angular12

I am using Angular 12 and I have a child component and using the @Input decorator.

So I have something like this:

```
 <hello
  isRed="true">
</hello>
```

Here is the child component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 class="{{redClass}}">Test</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; } .red { background: red }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {

  redClass;

  @Input() isRed: boolean = false;
}
```

isRed is currently boolean but I want a way to say: `if (isRed === true) { redClass = '.red' }`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template, just do

```html
<h1 [class.red]="isRed">Test</h1>
```

This will only apply `red` css class if `isRed` is truthy.

This approach will also update css if parent component updates the value of `isRed`. If you want to follow imperative approach, try to update `redClass` variable inside `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to define the input field as a setter like so:

```js
...

redClass = '';

@Input() 
set isRed(arg: boolean) {
  if(arg) {
     this.redClass = 'red';
  }           
}

...
```

And then in your parent component:

```html
<!-- the right isRed of the assignment is a property of the parent that holds true or false -->
<hello [isRed]="isRed"></hello>
```

Comment: I've updated the question so it's explained better...hope it helps

Comment: My answer got accepted, but I just want to say that this is a good option too (except for the assignment to `'.red'` that should be `'red'` without a dot in order for the css class to be applied correctly). Making `redClass` a getter that reads from `isRed` is also a possibility.

Comment: ShamPooSham yeah! you are right, I'll correct it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look at the value in ngOnInit or ngOnChange (use the latter if the input may change during the component's lifetime).

```
ngOnInit() {
    if(this.isRed){
        this.redClass = "red";
    }
}
```

or

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.isRed.currentValue){
        this.redClass = "red";
    }
}
```

Read about Angular lifecycle hooks [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence)